# Excluding Restricted Videos while using the YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API version 2.0 to retrieve videos.

I want to exclude videos that display the message "restricted from playback on certain sites... Watch on Youtube" on embedding the videos.

I have used the parameter format=5, but this does not help in filtering out these videos. Also, I have received the following permissions using which I am not able to decide whether the video will still display the above message on embedding

yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='commentVote' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='videoRespond' permission='moderated'/

yt:accessControl action='rate' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='embed' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='list' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='autoPlay' permission='allowed'/

yt:accessControl action='syndicate' permission='allowed'/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to filter out videos that are only playable on certain domains (or that are blocked on certain domains). This can be frustrating; I know.

This blog post has more information about the steps you can take to filter out videos that are not playable for other reasons: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jeff. Does the VideoEmbeddable parameter in version 3.0 help?

Comment: Also, since you are saying that filtering out these videos is not possible, it does create others problems -- For mobile developers, the rtsp links still get retrieved for the same videos and the user ends up viewing these videos without leaving the same domain... Basically the uploader is left frustrated because his playback restrictions aren't respected and it appears as if the developer is finding a work-around to make these videos play without actually visiting YouTube.

Comment: RTSP links are only exposed if the video has syndication enabled. This is a separate setting from enabling/disabling embedding. The videoEmbeddable parameter in v3 just looks at the same "embeddable" setting that format=5 covers in v2. It doesn't take domain-specific settings into account. I agree with your frustration about the domain-specific settings not being reflected in API responses, and I do hope that changes in the future, but I can't promise anything.